# iPhone emulator for Windows Mobile

Tags: iphone, windows-mobile

Say I want to develop applications for iPhone, but I only have a phone with Windows Mobile and for whatever reason I cannot switch to iPhone or buy a new phone.

Is there any iPhone emulator for Windows Mobile that would allow me to run apps on Windows Mobile 6? I have HTC HD2.

P.S. I'm not interested in emulators for any other platform.

Comment: I would recommend buying a (2nd hand?) iPod Touch.

Answer (score 7):

No there no is none, since the CocoaTouch platform is is not opensourced you can't really emulate the platform.

Nor is it possible to emulate iOS on your device, since iOS will require some specific hardware.

You will also need a Mac to develop app since Xcode will only run on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't do it without an iPhone and obviously a developer account in order to provision your device.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you should be asking something like" iOS emulator for windows", which is no.
Understand more about SDKs and emulators, you cannot emulate iOS on a actual WM device but a simulator in a computer; this is not a platform problem, it's a understanding problem, you can still code apps without iPhone and publish it, it's just skipping a step.

If you are on Mac OSX, your good to go, grab the SDK and use the emulator bundled with it 
BTW, even if you do get a iphone, you still need a computer with OSX and xcode installed to start coding

Comment: You should really check your code on a real device. Since the simulator only translate CocoaTouch to Cocoa. There is no way to make sure you app really works on the device without testing it.

Comment: that's totally true, especially with hardware related functions; i was just putting an example in the answer :)